# How to share a property between multiple WCF services installed on a local machine?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a Windows service hosting multiple WCF services. All of it running on a local machine (using NamePipe).
Is there a simple way to have these WCF services share a property? (I would rather not have them sharing a file).
I need this as each session instantiated within each WCF service will be getting a hold on a given hardware and the other WCF services need to know what is still available in order to be able to instantiate another session.
Each WCF service implements a different protocol, which is why I did not merge the lot. There will be one proxy for each host.

Comment: Use a distributed Cache.

Comment: Can you share some pointers?

Comment: Are you open to using a distributed Cache like Redis? Or even a cache in general hosted on the machine?

Comment: It depends on the complexity. My system is quite simple, so I don't wanna something overkill.

Comment: It will introduce complexity. Try the answer below.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras, I started looking into distributed cache as you recommended, but I cannot find a whole lot online. I found this pretty good [link](https://michaelscodingspot.com/cache-implementations-in-csharp-net/), but I cannot figure out how to share the cache between multiple/different WCF services. I understand how it would work between instances of a same service, but not the former. Any advice or example you could share on this? Thanks

Comment: You want to use something like Redis. Either installed on-prem or Azure Cache for Redis. Then use a Redis client https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis

Comment: Implementing a distributed cache is an advanced topic. Will require you to do some research/learning on it.

Comment: From what I found online, it did not sound too complicated to do using Microsoft libraries, but I guess I am not seeing the whole picture. Thanks, I'll check your link.

Comment: Microsoft does not have a distributed cache. That link you provided is showing how to use a Dictionary as a cache. Not the same thing.

Comment: That does explain things indeed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a *super simple* way of getting service instances to share a property, but you *could* create a custom host that derives from ServiceHost and have it implement a particular interface, say something like:

```
public interface ISharedStateContainer
{
  SharedState State { get; set; }
}
```

This interface would have to be known your services. Then, in your windows service project, you could make a custom service host:

```
public class CustomServiceHost: ServiceHost, ISharedStateContainer
{
   SharedState state;
   public SharedState State{ get{ return state; } set{ state=value; } }       
}
```

...and then when the windows service creates the wcf service host instances, it could inject the shared state:

```
var sharedState = new SharedState();

myServiceHost = new CustomServiceHost( typeof( MyService ) );
((ISharedStateContainer) myServiceHost).State = sharedState;

myOtherHost = new CustomServiceHost( typeof( OtherService ) );
((ISharedStateContainer) myOtherHost).State = sharedState;

myServiceHost.Open();
myOtherHost.Open();
```

...and then, in a *running instance* of a service, you could get to shared state like this:

```
var sharedState = ((ISharedStateContainer)OperationContext.Current.Host).State
```

Where I've got `SharedState`, you could make it any type you want...but making it a reference type that *itself* has properties means you can use it to share as many properties as you need. Note that with *any* shared state, you'll have race conditions to protect against.

I've done a windows service the same way (multiple different wcf service types)...and this is more-or-less how they share state.

**EDIT:**

I don't know why I didn't think about this sooner, but another nice way to share state is using a singleton. This is probably more straightforward than the earlier approach. I have this pattern going on, too...for a somewhat different reason, but it would serve for shared state, too:

```
public class SharedState
{
  //--> singleton instance...
  static readonly SharedState current;

  //--> use static initializer to create the current instance...
  static SharedState( )
  {
    current = new SharedState();
  }

  //--> hide ctor...
  private SharedState(){}

  public static SharedState Current
  {
    get { return current; }
  }

  //--> all your shared state instance methods and properties go here...

  public string SomeString
  {
    get
    {
      return //...
    }
  }

}
```

...and then you can get to this object from *anywhere in your service*, even from code not running in the context of a client operation. I use this for long running background task that the service needs to perform periodically, but shared properties are super easy:

```
var someValue = SharedState.Current.SomeString;
```

Comment: Will try that out. Thanks

Comment: I suppose there is no objection in Sharing an Object or even a delegate rather than a state variable?

Comment: Perfectly reasonable. I use `Function<...>` and `Action<...>` *properties* (on my `SharedState` object) to access shared functionality, but didn't want to cloud the answer with more off-center stuff. Sounds like you get the dynamics, though ;-)

Comment: When doing "var sharedState = ((ISharedStateContainer)OperationContext.Current.Host).State" from within my service I get the following error: System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.get returned null. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm...you can't access OperationContext.Current *except* during an actual client invocation. Lemme see if there's another path to the host. With `wcf` there are almost always multiple paths to things.

Comment: Hmm...you can't access `OperationContext.Current` *except* during an actual client invocation. Lemme see if there's another path to the host. With `wcf` there are almost always multiple paths to things.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep on investigating on my side too.

Comment: @toughQuestions, take a look at the edit. This is probably much more straightforward for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks @Clay, but this will not allow me to actually share data between 2 different WCF services or am I missing something?

Comment: Two different services running in the same exe? Yes, it will.

Comment: Both services need to reference the .dll that has the shared state...or you define it in the hosting environment. As long as they can get to it.

Comment: Seems to work as long as the WCF services are all part of the same namespace :-) Thanks mate!
Oh, just read your other replies… I guess we are saying the same thing :-)

Comment: Now it might be worth informing all the Services when this data gets modified. Maybe I should have some delegates for that!?

Comment: Yup...easy enough once you got the infrastructure in place ;-) Now keep in mind that normally a service instance is created per-call or per-session...so it doesn't tend to last long enough to hook events. If you've got singleton instances, it's another story, but that doesn't tend to scale as well.

Comment: Multiple clients will need to access the same service instance, so has to be singleton :-)
I have to create the instantiation from within a same singleton service (which is a bit crap), but I could not find another way. (As several bunch of clients need to talk with different service instances)